# Increasing sample size by 1 from previous loop?

Tags: r

I am attempting to plot the mean-variance from bootstrapped data against sample size.

I have set up a loop that randomly selects n lines of the bootstrapped data (total n=1000), finds the variance, returns the variance and does this 10 times. However, I would instead rather like to do this for each value going from n=2 to n=1000. I.e. It calculates the variance of a sample of 2, then 3, then 4, then 5... all the way to the variance of 1000 samples, as currently I am changing the sample size one by one. How is the best way to do this? my current code is as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
bSamples <- 10
bResults <- rep(NA, bSamples)


for (b in seq_len(bSamples)) { 
  bRows<-baseRan[sample(nrow(baseRan), 5), ]
  bValue <- var(bRows$Ranpopsize)
  bResults[[b]] <- bValue }

BR = data.frame(bResults)
BR
```

Comment: Do you want the sample size to vary from `2:1000`?

Answer (score 1):

(Edited to incorporate OP's request in comment.) You can adapt your loop to iterate over sample size and populate a dataframe with stats for each:

```
set.seed(1)

# example data
baseRan <- data.frame(id = 1:2000, Ranpopsize = rnorm(2000))  

# initialize result dataframe
n_range <- 2:1000
BR <- data.frame(
  n = n_range,
  var = vector("double", length(n_range)),
  mean = vector("double", length(n_range)),
  ci95.lo = vector("double", length(n_range)),
  ci95.hi = vector("double", length(n_range))
)

for (b in n_range) { 
  bRanpop <-baseRan[sample(nrow(baseRan), b), ]$Ranpopsize
  bMean <- mean(bRanpop)
  bConf <- (sd(bRanpop) / sqrt(b)) * 1.96
  BR[b - 1, -1] <- c(var(bRanpop), bMean, bMean - bConf, bMean + bConf)
}

head(BR)
#   n       var       mean    ci95.lo   ci95.hi
# 1 2 0.3568078  0.5214573 -0.3064052 1.3493199
# 2 3 3.2798144  0.1923345 -1.8570341 2.2417031
# 3 4 0.4607873  0.2721666 -0.3930703 0.9374034
# 4 5 0.9062647 -0.1553909 -0.9898376 0.6790558
# 5 6 1.3973509  0.5937734 -0.3521004 1.5396471
# 6 7 1.0208383 -0.1533831 -0.9018723 0.5951061
```

Plotting mean and 95% CI as a function of sample size:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(BR, aes(n, mean)) +
  geom_ribbon(
    aes(ymin = ci95.lo, ymax = ci95.hi),
    fill = "red",
    alpha = .3
  ) +
  geom_line(size = .2) +
  ylab("Mean (+/- 95% CI)") +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly! Is it possible to then use this to calculate the confidence interval of each sample size and plot it? So that you can see an approximate sample size for when 90%, 95% 99% etc. confidence intervals are reached?

Comment: Not sure what you mean — the confidence interval for what? Around the mean? I also don’t understand what you mean by when different confidence intervals “are reached.”

Comment: Sorry I'll try clarify. But yes, looking to plot the confidence interval width around the mean as well. E.g. for n=2 will have a very high confidence interval width, which should gradually decrease decrease as the sample size increases. I'd like to plot this as well, or would this require completely new lines of code? By "reaching a confidence limit" I just mean that once the confidence interval width reaches <0.10 would indicate a 90% confidence interval, <0.05, a 95% confidence interval. Does that make sense? Apologies I'm relatively new to R, especially loops like this, but Thank you SM!

Comment: See my edited answer. Would you mind editing your original question to include your CI request?